# React switching between queues (lists) bug

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working on an app that keeps track of salespeople's availability based on being either "Available" or "With Client".

Here's the bug I'm having. I'll use an example:

2 salespeople have been added to the app. The order in which they have been added to the app seems to matter in a way I don't expect to. For example, if the first salesperson I've added is James and the second is Rick, If I click on the button next to Rick that reads "Helped A Customer", James will now populate both the "Available" and the "With Client" tables, and Rick will have disappeared.

However if I click on them in a certain order, it works fine. For example, in the same situation as the example above, if I click on James' "Helped A Customer" first, then Rick's "Helped A Customer", then James' "No Longer With Customer", then Rick's "No Longer With Customer", it behaves as expected.

Here's the github project, you can clone it and try it out yourselves:
https://github.com/jackson-lenhart/salesperson-queue

I'll post what I think is the most relevant code here as well:

main.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import shortid from "shortid";
import deepCopy from "deep-copy";

import AddForm from "./add-form";
import Available from "./available";
import WithClient from "./with-client";

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      queue: {
        available: [],
        withClient: [],
        unavailable: []
      },
      currName: ""
    };

    this.addToQueue = this.addToQueue.bind(this);
    this.removeFromQueue = this.removeFromQueue.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
    this.move = this.move.bind(this);
  }

  addToQueue(name) {
    let newQueue = deepCopy(this.state.queue);
    newQueue.available = this.state.queue.available.concat({
      name,
      id: shortid.generate()
    });
    this.setState({
      queue: newQueue
    });
  }

  removeFromQueue(id) {
    let newQueue = deepCopy(this.state.queue);
    for (let k in this.state.queue) {
      newQueue[k] = this.state.queue[k].filter(x =>
        x.id !== id
      );
    }
    this.setState({
      queue: newQueue
    });
  }

  move(id, from, to) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      let newQueue = deepCopy(prevState.queue);
      let temp = newQueue[from].find(x => x.id === id);
      newQueue[from] = prevState.queue[from].filter(x =>
        x.id !== id
      );
      newQueue[to] = prevState.queue[to].concat(temp);
      return {
        queue: newQueue
      };
    });
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    this.setState({
      currName: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AddForm
          addToQueue={this.addToQueue}
          handleInput={this.handleInput}
          currName={this.state.currName}
        />
        <Available
          available={this.state.queue.available}
          move={this.move}
          removeFromQueue={this.removeFromQueue}
        />
        <WithClient
          withClient={this.state.queue.withClient}
          move={this.move}
          removeFromQueue={this.removeFromQueue}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(
  <Main />,
  document.body
);
```

add-form.js:

```
import React from "react";

class AddForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.clickWrapper = this.clickWrapper.bind(this);
  }

  clickWrapper() {
    this.props.addToQueue(this.props.currName);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.props.handleInput}
        />
        <button onClick={this.clickWrapper}>
          <strong>Add To Queue</strong>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddForm;
```

available.js:

```
import React from "react";

import Salesperson from "./salesperson";

class Available extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const style = {
      item: {
        padding: "10px"
      },
      available: {
        padding: "20px"
      }
    };

    let available;
    this.props.available.length === 0 ?
      available = (
        <p>None available.</p>
      ) : available = this.props.available.map(x =>
        <div key={x.id} style={style.item}>
          <Salesperson
            key={x.id}
            id={x.id}
            name={x.name}
            move={this.props.move}
            removeFromQueue={this.props.removeFromQueue}
            parent={"available"}
          />
        </div>
      );

    return (
      <div style={style.available}>
        <h1>Available</h1>
        {available}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Available;
```

salesperson.js:

```
import React from "react";

import DeleteButton from "./delete-button";
import HelpedButton from "./helped-button";
import NlwcButton from "./nlwc-button";

class Salesperson extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const style = {
      name: {
        padding: "10px"
      },
      button: {
        padding: "5px"
      }
    };

    let moveButton;
    switch(this.props.parent) {
      case "available":
        moveButton = (
          <HelpedButton
            move={this.props.move}
            id={this.props.id}
            style={style.button}
          />
        );
        break;
      case "withClient":
        moveButton = (
          <NlwcButton
            move={this.props.move}
            removeFromQueue={this.props.removeFromQueue}
            id={this.props.id}
            style={style.button}
          />
        );
        break;
      default:
        console.error("Invalid parent:", this.props.parent);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <span style={style.name}>{this.props.name}</span>
        {moveButton}
        <DeleteButton
          removeFromQueue={this.props.removeFromQueue}
          name={this.props.name}
          id={this.props.id}
          style={style.button}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Salesperson;
```

helped-button.js:

```
import React from "react";

class HelpedButton extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.clickWrapper = this.clickWrapper.bind(this);
  }

  clickWrapper() {
    this.props.move(this.props.id, "available", "withClient");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span style={this.props.style}>
        <button onClick={this.clickWrapper}>
          <strong>Helped A Customer</strong>
        </button>
      </span>
    );
  }
}

export default HelpedButton;
```

Comment: I cloned your repo and could not find the issue mentioned. For me on clicking 'Helped A Customer' against `Rick` after adding both `James` and `Rick`; 'James` is displayed as `Available` and `Rick` as `With client`

Comment: @Gautam I found out what the issue was, it was a silly typo. Here's the commit: https://github.com/jackson-lenhart/salesperson-queue/commit/b86271a20ac8b700bec1e15e001b0c6ef57adb8b sorry to waste your time

Answer (score 0):

This was just a typo on my part. No longer an issue. Here's the commit that fixed the typo:
https://github.com/jackson-lenhart/salesperson-queue/commit/b86271a20ac8b700bec1e15e001b0c6ef57adb8b